# R Tuning Binary Prediction Threshold

Tags: r, performance, prediction, threshold, imbalanced-data

I am running a multilevel binary logistic regression (MLBLR) model using *glmer*. After having trained the MLBLR on the training data (which was created using *Tidymodels*), I now intend to tune/calibrate the prediction probability threshold. I hereby want to maximise Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC). Do you have an idea how I could best do this when building upon the following code?

I tried it via a for loop in which I tried recreating the MCC formula for each cutoff value. However, when plotting the results for the different cutoffs I cannot distinguish a fitting cutoff value, even when I have more detailed data.

MCC formula:
[MCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKUJy.png)

MCC = (TP*TN-FP*FN)/sqrt((TP+FP)(TP+FN)(TN+FP)(TN+FN))

Code:
(Reproducable Example):

```
Df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~year_week,~Runner,~NewRRI,~Distance, ~HR, ~Gender,~Age,~BMI,~PreviousRRI,
   "2019-41", "M01"  ,      0,     5000, 120,  "Male",  23,  18,        1,   
   "2019-41", "M02"  ,      0,     6000, 125,"Female",  36,  20,        0,
   "2019-41", "M03"  ,      0,     8000, 130,  "Male",  56,  21,        0,
   "2019-42", "M01"  ,      0,     5500, 122,  "Male",  23,  18,        1,
   "2019-42", "M02"  ,      0,     7000, 128,"Female",  36,  20,        0,
   "2019-42", "M03"  ,      0,    15000, 132,  "Male",  56,  21,        0,
   "2019-43", "M01"  ,      1,     3000, 120,  "Male",  23,  18,        1,
   "2019-43", "M02"  ,      0,     9000, 127,"Female",  36,  20,        0,
   "2019-43", "M03"  ,      0,     9500, 131,  "Male",  56,  21,        0,
   "2019-44", "M01"  ,      0,    15000, 125,  "Male",  23,  18,        1,
   "2019-44", "M02"  ,      0,     9000, 127,"Female",  36,  20,        0,
   "2019-44", "M03"  ,      0,     9500, 131,  "Male",  56,  21,        0,
  ) %>%
  mutate(Gender = as.factor(Gender),
         PreviousRRI = as.factor(PreviousRRI),
         NewRRI = as.factor(NewRRI),
         Runner = as.factor(Runner))

library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(themis)
library(caret)
library(lme4)

# Split data
Df <- Df %>% arrange(year_week)
Df_splits <- initial_time_split(Df, prop = 0.8)
RunningData_train <- training(Df_splits)
RunningData_test <- testing(Df_splits)

# Rescale
RunningData_train_norm <- preProcess(RunningData_train)
RunningData_train <- predict(RunningData_train_norm, RunningData_train)
RunningData_test <- predict(RunningData_train_norm, RunningData_test)

# MLBLR model
MLBR_L <- glmer(NewRRI ~ Distance + HR + Gender + Age + BMI + PreviousRRI + (1|Runner), 
                data = RunningData_train,
                family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
                nAGQ = 1)
# Tune probability value
cutoffs <- seq(0.1,0.9,0.1)
mcc <- NULL
for (i in seq(along = cutoffs)){
  prediction <- ifelse(MLBR_L@resp[[".->mu"]] >=cutoffs[i],1,0) # Predictions
  mcc <- c(mcc, (length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == prediction) && which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == 1))*#TP
                   length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == prediction) && which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == 0))-#TN
                   length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI != prediction) && which(prediction == 1))*#FP
                   length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI != prediction) && which(prediction == 0)))/#FN
             sqrt(
               (length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == prediction) && which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == 1))+#TP
                  length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI != prediction) && which(prediction == 1)))*#FP
                 (length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == prediction) && which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == 1))+#TP
                    length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI != prediction) && which(prediction == 0)))*#FN
                 (length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == prediction) && which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == 0))+#TN
                    length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI != prediction) && which(prediction == 1)))*#FP
                 (length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == prediction) && which(RunningData_train$NewRRI == 0))+#TN
                    length(which(RunningData_train$NewRRI != prediction) && which(prediction == 0)))#FN
               )
             )
}

# Inspect best MCC value:
plot(cutoffs, mcc, pch = 19, type='b',
     xlab="Cutoff Level", ylab = "MCC")

# Later take the cutoff value with the best MCC on training data and use it for test set prediction:
Predictions <- RunningData_test %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Prediction = predict(MLBR_L, RunningData_test, type = "response"),
                Prediction = ifelse(Prediction > .5, 1, 0),  ## Take the best cutoff value then
                Prediction = factor(Prediction, levels = c("0", "1")),
                NewRRI = factor(NewRRI, levels = c("0", "1")))
# Check MCC
mcc(RunningData_test, Predictions$NewRRI, Predictions$Prediction)
```

Thank you for your help in advance, kind regards!

Comment: `multilevelmod` is not a CRAN package, where can we find it?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hey Rui, I am sorry this package slipped in, it is actually not needed for this code, and is indeed not available on CRAN. However, I retrieved it from GitHub: https://github.com/tidymodels/multilevelmod

Comment: There's not enough data to estimate the parameters: *"Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined"*. As a result the cutoff plot is a flat line at zero and the MCC is `NA`.